# VMWare - Jumbo Frames over iSCSI to a NAS4Free array

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, iscsi, mtu, jumboframes

I am having problems getting Jumbo Frames working over my iSCSI connection.

Here is what I try.

- 4 1GbE connections on 4 different subnets on my NAS4Free array for iSCSI, MTU set at 9000
- 2 redunant switches with the MTU set at their maximum 12288(or something like that)
- 1 vSwitch MTU 9000
- 4 vNICs MTU 9000

If I turn the vNICs MTU from 1500 to 9000 everything stops working, I can't even turn on or off a VM on the associated datastore.

Comment: Do you *need* Jumbo frames?

Comment: From what I had researched if I can turn it on it is beneficial to do so. And I have a SAN unti from Dell that appears to support Jumbo Frames and only Jumbo Frames.

Comment: @ewwhite They generally make sense on something like ISCSI  - the overhead and packet reduction can seriously take load of the network in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I have punted for this array, the problem I am having seems to be pointing back at the NAS4Free array, since I can use 9000 MTU for VMotion just fine (over the same NICs and switches, just different vNICs). I am going to create two iSCSI storage networks, one that operates as 1500 MTU and one that operates at 9000 MTU. When I transition my other SAN units to the cluster I will attempt to get them working on the Jumbo Frame network.